# Add Column To List Records Sequentially By Date

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, sequential

I have a table with a bunch of dates in random order. How could I add a column that would sequentially number the dates in descending order.

ORIGINAL TABLE

```
ID   DATE
1    10/08/15
2    10/06/15
3    10/11/15
4    10/07/15
```

MODIFIED TABLE

```
ID   DATE       ORDER
1    10/08/15   2
2    10/06/15   4
3    10/11/15   1
4    10/07/15   3
```

Comment: Why do you need this?  Is it not enough to return the data in `ORDER BY DATE`?

Comment: Typically you would just run a query that does this: `SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY DATE`

Comment: @TrippKinetics There are many cases where you need a row_id to join a different table

Comment: I am creating test data that needs to trend over a specified date for a bunch of subsets of related data. I decided to do so by iterating through each subset of data. makes it possible by having an id that i can reference with a @COUNTER variable

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza But what would be gained by setting that id arbitrarily?

Comment: @wellmannered Gotcha.  Then Giorgi Nakeuri's answer should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With window functions:

```
select *, row_number() over(order by date desc) as [order] from tablename
```

Comment: how would I take this temporarily created column and permanently add it as a column of that table?

Comment: You add column manually and then update it with statement:  `;with cte as(select *, row_number() over(order by date desc) as [order] from tablename) update cte set newcolumn = [order]`